# Find value in API GET request JSON Data

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am making an API call to pull back some JSON data

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/vnd.y+json;version=2' --header 'Authorization: Token token=nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 'https://api.myapi/PBHBP1E?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=notification_rules&include%5B%5D=teams'
```

Returns something like....

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "mtirza@xxxxxxxxx.com",
    "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "color": "dark-olive-green",
    "avatar_url": "https://sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "billed": true,
    "role": "team_responder",
    "description": null,
    "invitation_sent": false,
    "contact_methods": [
      {
        "id": "P6G5LDE",
        "type": "email_contact_method",
        "summary": "Default",
        "self": "https://api.myapi/P6G5LDE",
        "html_url": null,
        "label": "Default",
        "address": "mtirza@xxxxxxxxx.com",
        "send_short_email": false,
        "send_html_email": true
      },
      {
        "id": "PV67YL2",
        "type": "phone_contact_method",
        "summary": "Mobile",
        "self": "https://api.myapi/PV67YL2",
        "html_url": null,
        "label": "Mobile",
        "address": "123456",
        "country_code": 1,
        "blacklisted": false
      }
    ]

}
```

I am using whats returns in some HTML, my question is, I want to look for the `"type"` `phone_contact_method` and pull back `"address"`
as I'm not sure which array of `data.user.contact_methods[?]` it will be in but I know I will always want

```
data.user.contact_methods.Type.phone_contact_method.address
```

Is this possible using something similar to the below?

```
function Request(endpoint, options) {
    $.ajax($.extend({}, {
        async: false,   
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    $('.Name').html(data.user.name);     // John Smith
    $('.Email').html(data.user.email);   // mebmirza@xxxxxxxxx.com
    $('.Phone').html(data.user.contact_methods[1].address); // 123456

},
    url: "https://api.myapi/" + endpoint,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2"
    }
  },
  options));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fail-safe way would be to use [`Array.prototype.find(callback[, thisArg])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

---

```
var contact_method = data.user.contact_methods.find(method => method.type === "phone_contact_method");
if (contact_method !== undefined) {
    $('.Phone').html(contact_method.address);
}
```

```js
var data = {
  "user": {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "mtirza@xxxxxxxxx.com",
    "contact_methods": [{
      "id": "P6G5LDE",
      "type": "email_contact_method",
      "address": "mtirza@xxxxxxxxx.com",
    }, {
      "id": "PV67YL2",
      "type": "phone_contact_method",
      "address": "123456",
    }]
  }
};

$('.Name').html(data.user.name);     // John Smith
$('.Email').html(data.user.email);   // mebmirza@xxxxxxxxx.com
$('.Phone').html(data.user.contact_methods[1].address); // 123456

var contact_method = data.user.contact_methods.find(method => method.type === "phone_contact_method");
if (contact_method !== undefined) {
  $('.Phone').html(contact_method.address);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name: <span class="Name"></span></p>
<p>Email: <span class="Email"></span></p>
<p>Phone: <span class="Phone"></span></p>
```

Comment: Sorry but this works better than the above! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general (eg unless the webservice specifically defines it) you should not assume the order of elements in any array. If you want to find one particular element based on the presence or value of a particular attribute, then you'll have to iterate through the array.

Assuming you are content to take the first array element `i` such that `data.user.contact_methods[i].type == 'phone_contact_method'`, then you can make use of the [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method as follows:

```
function Request(endpoint, options) {
    //...
    success: function(data) {
    $('.Name').html(data.user.name);     // John Smith
    $('.Email').html(data.user.email);   // mebmirza@xxxxxxxxx.com

    var address = data.user.contact_methods.find(function (el) {
        return el.type == 'phone_contact_method';
    });

    $('.Phone').html(address); // 123456
},
// ...
```

The find method uses the function you specify in order to select an element from an array.

Comment: Excellent sir, thank you for the great response. Just what I needed